# jQuery: Eventhandler works only once

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click

Maybe you heard of the [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com). It's an usual jQuery slider for all kinds of content. I use it and I want something to happen every time I click on the "next" or "previous" control buttons. Right below the body - tag I load jQuery. The following script is placed on the bottom of the page.

My problem is, that the function 'loadNext' is only called once. Not even the .click is triggered. Why is that? There are no errors in console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

    // Initializing the slider, not that important for you, I guess   
    var viewWidth = $(window).width();
    slider = $('#carouselSlider').bxSlider({
        minSlide: 1,
        maxSlide: 1,
        slideWidth: viewWidth,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true
    });

    // Initializing a 2nd slider inside the previous (main)slider. That works fine.
    $('.tada').bxSlider({
        startSlide: 0,
        controls: false,
        minSlide: 1,
        maxSlide: 1,
        slideWidth: 600,
        pagerCustom: '.bx-pager-own'
    });

    // This function should be called. Works fine (once).
    function loadNext() {
        currentSlide = slider.getCurrentSlide();
        var chainIDs = <?php echo json_encode($allChainIDs); ?>;
        var dataToSend = {'currentSlide' : currentSlide, 'chainIDs[]' : <?php echo json_encode($allChainIDs); ?> } ;


        //Main Images
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./backend/getImages.php",
            data: dataToSend,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){                    
            $("#"+ chainIDs[currentSlide + 1]).html(html);
            slider.reloadSlider({
                 startSlide: currentSlide
            });
            }
        }); 
    }   


    var steps = 0;
    var prevsteps = 0;

    // I assume, that the problem is lying here
    $('a.bx-next').click( function() {
        console.log("Clicked 'next'"); // that happens only once!!
        steps++;
        if(steps % 1 == 0 && steps > prevsteps){
        loadNext();
        prevsteps = steps;
        }
    });

    $('a.bx-prev').click( function() {
        steps--;

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Are this buttons `a.bx-next` ,`a.bx-prev` loading dynamically..?

Comment: No, only the content is loading dynamically. Those buttons are there from the beginning.

Comment: Can you create a runnable example at http://jsfiddle.net? Providing runnable examples is the best way to get others to help you. That means shrinking your code down to only the problematic parts (which sometimes solves the problem and you don't even need to post a question)

Comment: Yes @JuanMendes, I thought about that, but the rest of the page is to complex to shrink it to an essential code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that

```
slider.reloadSlider({
    startSlide: currentSlide
});
```

recreates the slider elements. Which breaks the click event handler, since the original button gets replaced.

You could change it to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and it should work. For example.

```
$('body').on('click','a.bx-next',function() {
    console.log("Clicked 'next'"); // that happens only once!!
    steps++;
    if(steps % 1 == 0 && steps > prevsteps){
    loadNext();
    prevsteps = steps;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks Andy . Never thought about a breaking event handler since it tries to listen on a class. Works fine now!